# DatetimeArray to dtype datetime64 in Linux but good in Windows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Python3 program that reads an Excel file using Pandas. The program works well in Windows 10 (Python3.7), but throws an error in Ubuntu server (Python3.5). The trace says it is a pandas problem. Did anyone experience the same? How to resolve it?

```
    df = pandas.read_excel(source, sheet_name='Sheet1', converters = { 'Date Time': pandas.to_datetime})
    df['Date Time'] = df['Date Time'].dt.tz_localize('US/Mountain').dt.tz_convert('UTC')
    df['Net Load Forecast'] = df['Net Load Forecast'].fillna(0.0).astype(int)
    df['target_hour'].astype('datetime64') #<<---this line throws error in Ubuntu
```

Error

```
 File "data_ftp_to_etrm_import.py", line 72, in <module>
    df['target_hour'] = df['target_hour'].astype('datetime64')
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5681, in astype
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 531, in astype
    return self.apply('astype', dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 395, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 534, in astype
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 2139, in _astype
    return super(DatetimeBlock, self)._astype(dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 616, in _astype
    values = self.values.astype(dtype)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py", line 642, in astype
    return dtl.DatetimeLikeArrayMixin.astype(self, dtype, copy)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimelike.py", line 540, in astype
    raise TypeError(msg.format(name=type(self).__name__, dtype=dtype))
```